# how to use resource files in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, resource-files

i want to know the correct path to put my resource files in a web application in sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 3):

For a nice tutorial on how to use resource files in SharePoint 2010, check:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnwpowell/sharepoint-2010-localization-with-visual-studio-2010)